# how can liferay alloy ui validation error be captured for web analytics?

Tags: javascript, validation, liferay, matomo, alloy-ui

Im using liferay with piwik and would like to capture client side validation error events into a custom variable in piwik.  For e.g. the default user registration page has a number of fields and alloy ui validators configured.  I want to capture all validation errors encountered by a registering user in piwik for analysis and possible improvement of the user experience..

I would prefer to do this centrally so that all form validations are trapped for piwik.  Could not really figure out how the alloy ui validator framework is organized.  There seems to be way too much magic happening in there.

i simply hit submit button on an empty registration form and found that the class `aui-form-validator-error-container` is being added on blur and submit to tag error fields.  I failed to identify the code that makes all of this magic happen.

Would some one have some pointers for me on how to go about this?

Comment: I understand that you know how to use custom variable in PIWIK ?

Comment: Yes I do. What I'm looking for is a way to implement this centrally rather than on a case by case basis

Comment: You can create another page. This page will generate the javascript for saving custom variable. Just pass custom variable name and its value to this page and add the script generate to current page. The call to this page can come from any page. This way it can be handle centrally. Remember : Piwik allows 5 custom variables per page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it helps but you can refer to your

{liferay_tomcat_home}/webapps/root/html/js/aui/aui-form-validator/aui-form-validator.js

It contains the actual javascript used during rendering.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you should need to get what you want:

1. Listen to the `form:registered` event to get the instantiated forms.
2. Listen to the `submitError` event on the `formValidator` of each of the forms.
3. Use the `event.validator.errors` to check which `fields` had errors.

Something like this should work:

```
Liferay.on('form:registered', function(event) {
    event.form.formValidator.on('submitError', function(event) {
        console.log(event.validator.errors);
    });
});
```

Additionally, you can also listen to `errorField` and `validField` on the `formValidator` to individual field notifications.